# What would be the answer for this question?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I got a question form an angular interview. 
The interviewer asked what does this code means in angular?

code;

```
<app-main [type]="text"></app-main>
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: You should do some reading on Angular parameters and inputs/outputs

Answer (score 6):

That is the property binding syntax using `[]` anotation

You are passing `text` variable value from component to the child component `app-main`

In the `app-main` it's expecting some value to be pass down like this

```
@Input() type: string;
```

You can read it more [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

It's a input provided to the app component from the view you are currently in.
For this you use `@Input` decor with the same name which has been passed under `[xyz]` 
.
so in app component you declare a variable as `@Input('xyz',{static:true / false }) myVariableInAppComp ;`

now feel free to use  `myVariableInAppComp` in your app component.

here `static:true /false` refer to lifecycle hooks which you can look into.